# Error "function 'repository_rule' does not exist" while trying to compile tensorflow

Tags: linux, tensorflow, gpu, bazel

I am trying to compile tensorflow and has the following error:

```
dims@nebula3:~/tensorflow$ ./configure
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /usr/bin/python]:
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [y/N]
No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Hadoop File System support? [y/N]
No Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Found possible Python library paths:
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with GPU support? [y/N]
No GPU support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Configuration finished
INFO: Starting clean (this may take a while). Consider using --expunge_async if the clean takes more than several minutes.
......
ERROR: /home/dims/tensorflow/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl:509:18: function 'repository_rule' does not exist.
ERROR: com.google.devtools.build.lib.packages.BuildFileContainsErrorsException: error loading package 'external': Extension 'third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl' has errors.
```

I don't have any CUDA on machine (it's virtual) and so I have selected no GPU in configure. But nevertheless, configure swears on CUDA.

**UPDATE**

```
dims@nebula3:~$ bazel version
Build label: 0.2.0
Build target: bazel-out/local_linux-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Tue Feb 23 13:08:29 2016 (1456232909)
Build timestamp: 1456232909
Build timestamp as int: 1456232909
```

Comment: It looks like you are using an old version of Bazel. What does `bazel version` says?

Comment: See my update please. I was running `bazel upgrade` as instructed.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?!

Comment: @putonspectacles don't remember :) but was able to comple finally :)

Comment: @Dims me too! but what version of tf, and bazel are you using now?